# Flex-grow in Figma auto layout?

Tags: layout, figma

Say I have the following layout:

```
----Left Component--Central Component--Right Component---
```

The parent component has a fixed width. I'd like Figma to auto-resize the width of left component and the right component based on available space, that is, the parent's width minus the central component's width. In CSS, I can achieve this via the `flex-grow` property.

Is there an equivalent in Figma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figma got this feature recently and it's called **Auto Layout v3**.
You can find more info [on Figma's own blog](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040451373-Create-dynamic-designs-with-Auto-Layout) and learn more of it on [Figma's YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4K2m-3MmQQ).

Answer (score 1):

As of [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FigmaDesign/comments/hcj34e/flexgrow_in_figma_auto_layout/) on Reddit, it seems that this is not possible, as of June 2020 at least.

Comment: Yup, the responsiveness in Figma and Xd has its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [auto-layout](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040451373-Create-dynamic-designs-with-Auto-Layout)

Set the left and right components inside the auto layout to have a "resize". setting for "Fill container". Then changing the width of the middle component will shrink and expand the side components to fill the width of the parent container.

```
--Left Component (resize: Fill Container)
--Central Component (resize: Default Setting)
--Right Component (resize: Fill Container)--
```

[image]